# Что такое session?

Tags: сессия, cookie, php

Объясните, пожалуйста, незнающему. В чем разница между `session` и `cookies`? Можно ли применить что-то одно без ущерба функционированию сайта? (Насколько я понял механизм сессии использует куки) И как сделать так, чтобы браузер сам предлагал сохранить пароли при первом посещении.

P.S. И не надо отправлять меня сразу к [Google](http://google.ru), ибо там я ничего не понял.

Comment: Под "предлагал сохранить пароли" вы что понимаете? Какие, от чего, при заполнении или открытии страницы и т.п. Поконкретнее, можно пошагово.

Comment: Как почтовик. Хотелось бы чтобы при авторизации сайт предложил сохранить пароль. (если пользователь отметит галочку "запомнить меня")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Механизм сессий использует куки для хранения sessionid, и все. Разница банальна - куки на клиенте, сессия на сервере, следствия логичны - куки места на сервере не занимют, сессии недоступны для прямого чтения и изменения юзером. То есть в сессии вполне можно хранить пароль в открытом виде, например, хотя и не рекомендуется на всякий случай. Также размер куков ограничен, а в сессии вполне можно хранить довольно большие объемы данных, объекты и прочее.

Еще - сессия работает до закрытия браузера или до истечения серверного таймаута на хранение, куки можно поставить хоть на 10 лет. То есть, куки надо использовать для более долгих сроков (галка "запомнить меня", например).

**UPD:(запомнить)** Условие: в БД хранится md5-хэш от пароля, так много где сделано

```
$auth = $USER = false;
$hash = '';
// сначала пробуем слепить хэш из запроса
if (!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
  $hash = md5($_POST['login'].'###'.md5($_POST['password']));
// потом из сессии
if (!$hash && !empty($_SESSION['authhash']))
  $hash = $_SESSION['authhash'];
// потом из куки
if (!$hash && !empty($_COOKIE['authhash']))
  $hash = $_COOKIE['authhash'];
// если хоть где-то хэш заполнен, пробуем авторизоваться
if ($hash) {
  $quser = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE MD5(CONCAT(`username`, "###", `password`))="'.musql_real_escape_string($hash).'" LIMIT 1;');
  if ($USER = mysql_fetch_object($quser)) {
    $auth = true;
    $_SESSION['authhash'] = $hash;
    }
  if ($auth && !empty($_POST['remember']))
    setcookie('authhash', $hash, time()+60*60*24*7); // ставим куку на неделю
  }
// здесь нам доступны $auth и $USER
```

Примерно так. Могут быть ошибки, но суть вроде передал.

Comment: Т.е. сессия создает куку. А внутри куки всего-навсего `session_id`?

Comment: Можно сказать и так, основное различие в том что кука хранится на компе пользователя, а сессия на серваке

Comment: > Т.е. сессия создает куку. А внутри куки всего-навсего session_id?

Да. То есть эта кука отправляется каждый раз (как и любая другая) и по ее значению сервер подгружает файл сессии, где уже может быть много других данных.

Реализация "запомнить меня" - просто если соответствующее поле заполнено, сервер делает так: создает "хэш авторизации", что-то вроде `MD5($login.'###'.MD5($password))` и ставит его в куки. Соответственно, если кука установлена, юзер авторизуется по ней. Добавил примерную реализацию в ответ.