# Что такое сессии и куки?

Tags: веб-программирование, cookie, сессия

Не понимаю, как работает механизм сессий и куки. Что это вообще такое? Смотрел на разных сайтах, но плохо понимал, что это такое. Пожалуйста обьясните!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/58624

Comment: Если очень грубо, то куки это данные, которые хранятся у пользователя на компуктере и могут быть высланы с http запросом на какой-нибудь сервер.

Comment: Спасибо за обьяснения!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все взаимодействия между браузерами и серверами осуществляются при помощи протокола HTTP, который не сохраняет своё состояние (stateless). Данный факт означает, что сообщения между клиентом и сервером являются полностью независимыми один от другого — то есть не существует какого-либо представления "последовательности", или поведения в зависимости от предыдущих сообщений. В результате, если вы хотите создать сайт который будет отслеживать взаимодействие с клиентом (браузером), вам нужно реализовать это самостоятельно.

Сессии являются механизмом, который использует интернет для отслеживания "состояния" между сайтом и каким-либо браузером. Сессии позволяют вам хранить произвольные данные браузера и получать их в тот момент, когда между данным браузером и сайтом устанавливается соединение. Данные получаются и сохраняются в сессии при помощи соответствующего "ключа

Comment: Спасибо! Очень доходчиво!